# Float Nav is extending beyond container and also White Space between Nav and Banner, But why?

Tags: css, html

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I have done my fair bit of research and from what I understand 100% height should extend to the parent container's height. But for some reason my nav is extending beyond it. [A Screenshot HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDq6e.png) and [Screenshot CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b95rO.png)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sumnah-Home</title>
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="utf-8">    
</head>
   <body class="index">

       <article>
           <table  class="banner" >
               <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" class="banner"><span class="bannerText">Sunny Mtn. School of Nartural Healing</span></td>
                    <td><img class="banner" src="images/3_MemorialDay_t13681a.jpg"></td>
                    <td><img class="banner" src="images/MemorialDay.jpg"></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
       </article>

       <article class="nav">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Sumnah-Home</a> </li>
                <li><a href="information.html">Information Bulletin</a></li>
                <li><a href="information.html" >SPANISH</a></li>
                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="Registration">Registration</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html">Sunny Mtn News</a></li>
            </ul>
       </article>
       <img class="logo" src="images/sunnmn-logo.jpg" alt="Sunny Mountain School of Natural Healing">


      <article class ="content">
        <p class ="content_left">Sunny Mountain School of Natural healing has designed its programs of external, independent studies for busy, working or professional people who desire a high level of excellence in Natural Healing. Naturopathy is a system of health restoration and maintenance which emphasizes natural health modalities instead of drugs. It embraces: herbs, vitamins, minerals, sound nutrition, sun therapy, hydrotherapy, massage, etc.
        This program is ideal for persons who have acquired sufficient levels of mental discipline to study independently in their homes and at their own pace, under the guidance of our school.</p> 

          <p class="highlightLeft"><b>See Information Bulletin for more details...</b></p>







        <p class="content_right"><img class="flag" src="images/flag2.png" alt="American Flag">Operating for nearly two decades, Sunny Mountain School of Natural healing has designed its programs of external, independent studies for busy, working or professional people who desire a high level of excellence in Natural Healing. Naturopathy is a system of health restoration and maintenance which emphasizes natural health modalities instead of drugs. It embraces: herbs, vitamins, minerals, sound nutrition, sun therapy, hydrotherapy, massage, etc. This program is ideal for persons who have acquired sufficient levels of mental discipline to study independently in their homes and at their own pace, under the guidance of our school.</p>

          <p class="highlightRight"><b>See About us for more details...</b></p>


      </article>
    <article></article>
    <footer>All rights reserved.</footer>
    </body> 


</html>
```

Here is the CSS

```
/*----- Page Style------*/
html {    
    background-color: #6699CC;
}

body.index {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 860px;
    height: 842px;
}

/*----- Banner Style------*/
table.banner{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px -1px;

}

td.banner{
    color: white;
    background-color: #003366;

}

span.bannerText{   
    display: block;
    width:300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

img.banner{

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


/*----- Navigation Style------*/

article.nav{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

ul{
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #CCCC99;
    height: 100%;
}

ul.menu li{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 160px;
    height: 25px;
    background:#003366;
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
    margin: 0px 0px 2px;


}
/*----- Links Style------*/

ul.menu li a{
    color:white;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px;
}



/*-----Image Style-----*/
img.logo{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-top: 15px;

}

img.flag{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}


/*-----Heading Style----*/
article.heading{
    text-align: center;
}


/*-----Content Style----*/

article.content{
    margin: 280px 0px 0px 180px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 385px;
    position: relative;
}

p.highlightLeft{
     text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    font-weight: 1000px;
}

p.highlightRight{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    font-weight: 1000px;
    right: 0px;
}

p.content_left {
    width: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

p.content_right {
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -50px;
}

/*----Footer Style-----*/
Footer{

   width: 860px;
   height: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #333333;
   color: white;
   padding-top: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Instead of screenshots share your code here.

Comment: Okay added the code

Answer (score 0):

Your element which has 100% height is extending beyond the page because it is 
the same height as `<body>`, which is the containing element. **However, you have not taken into account the height of the header.**

Be careful when using 100% height: it will only work as expected if it's parent element has a fixed height.

Another thing to watch out for is that the browser will add padding to the 100% height unless you use `box-sizing: border-box` in which case the padding will be *included* in the 100%.

Comment: Thanks will give that a shot.

Comment: Okay Jake my Nav , article.nav, is parented inside body, body.index. My body.index has margin 0px auto (so that it can be centered) and a fixed height of 842px. Are you saying that I should remove the margin property out of my body all together?

Comment: no @PrimitiveCreations, that won't help you here. But you'll have to either lay this out differently (preferred) or give the header a specific height (say 100px) and then make the nav take that into account, like: `height: calc(100% - 100px)`.  However, while the latter would work, there are better ways to do this.

Comment: Ahh I see what would be the recommended route, or layout? I am recreating this website(http://sumnah.org/) from scratch, this is my first so any direction would be appreciated.